# Partcover: Exclude multiple namespaces via commandline

Tags: partcover

I'm using **Partcover** to generate code coverage statistic and want to exclude multiple namespaces using commandline parameter **--exclude**.

I can't manage to specify multiple namespaces to be excluded, could anyone suggest how to do it? Obviously single namespace mask working well.

Comment: As it looks like you have just started have you looked at PartCovers little brother OpenCover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add a --exclude for each assembly/namespace combination

i.e. --exclude [Assembly*]Namespace1.* --exclude [Assembly*]Namespace2.*

Comment: Just managed to do it, the problem was that I've used semicolon symbol to separate namespaces and a slightly wrong mask, shame to me :(
Anyway thanks!

Comment: If you downloaded PartCover with the installer then it should have an RTF manual which describes the commandline